# Wait for docker compose command in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker-compose, child-process

I want to start a docker compose file using Javascript on Node.js for integration tests. I'm able to execute the docker command in a child process using Nodes `exec` or `execSync` calls like this:

```js
import { execSync } from "node:child_process";

execSync("docker compose up -d")
```

The container are starting properly. However, the script should wait until the containers are completely up and running before it continues with the actual tests. I don't know how to do so.

My current workaround is to put the process to sleep for some time.

```js
execSync("docker compose up -d");

await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, "3000"));
```

But obviously I want to do it more elegant with proper event handling, so that the script can continue with the tests right after the containers are ready.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `-d` option. That should work assuming your compose file ensures all your dependencies are up and running e.g. that your services won't start until a db is up and running.

Comment: That indeed fixed it. I also had to use `exec()` again, so the working solution looks like this: `exec("docker compose up");` thanks!